# Codemirror editor cursor set to the right

Tags: css, codemirror

I have to align my textarea on the right of the page. So I have my textarea code as follows.

```
    <td  align="right"  >  
                <textarea style="align:left" id="scriptevalresult" name="scriptevalresult" cols="64" rows="4"></textarea>
    </td>
```

Because I have align="right" for the , my codemirror editor is set to the right of the editor.

how to resolve this.

Comment: why would you want to align the `textarea` at all? it is hidden when codemirror loads.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CSS rule like `.CodeMirror { text-align: left; }` to override this.